# Check for file in intervals until timeout value expired

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to poll for whether out put file created in a specific directory after a script is invoked in background and then returning from the method execution.

Is that achievable using Timer and Callable. Anything available in spring framework with out using low level Thread.sleep?

Comment: Use Java's [**WatchService**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) Class for this sort of thing

Comment: I'm checking for remote file using jsch and this is spring application. Any samples?